# Visualization of Compact Set in a Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

What is an intuitive and correct way to visualize a compact subset of a metric space?

Obviously, any compact subset $E$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is closed and bounded, but I have been informed that, for some metric spaces, $(E$ closed & bdd.$)\not\to (E$ compact$)$, so the visualization of "closed & bounded" is incorrect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A compact subset of a metric space is a compact metric space in its own right. Therefore your question can be read as: How can I visualize a compact metric space?

You have to swallow that compactness is a **subtle finiteness condition**. There are various "intuitive" approaches to this notion. Most simpleminded is the idea that in a compact space you cannot get lost. Another description is the following: Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and assume that for each $x\in X$  a guard placed at $x$ can survey a neighborhood $U_\epsilon(x)$, where $\epsilon>0$ is given in advance. Then finitely many suitably placed guards can survey all of $X$. But we can say even more: Assume that for each $x\in X$  a guard placed at $x$ can survey a certain neighborhood $U(x)$, depending on the local topography. Then finitely many suitably placed guards can survey all of $X$.